# Python Program on Perfect Squares

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote this python function which takes a list as a parameter and determines which elements of the list are perfect squares and then returns a new list of just those select elements.

Here is my function:

```
def square(n):
    return n**2

def perfectSquares1(L):
    import math
    m=max(L)
    for n in L:
        if type(n) is int and n>0:
            Result=map(square,range(1,math.floor(math.sqrt(m))))
            L1=list(Result)
    L2=list(set(L).intersection(set(L1)))
    return L2
```

But now I'm trying to re-work it a little: I want to write a one-line Boolean function that takes n as a parameter and returns True if n is a perfect square and returns false otherwise.

Any advice? I can't figure out a way to make it only one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
import math
def perfect_sq(n):
    return n == int(math.sqrt(n)) * int(math.sqrt(n))
```

Or you can use:

```
import math
def perfect_sq(n):
    return n == int(math.sqrt(n)) ** 2
```

Comment: Wasn't my downvote, but `perfect_sq(11)` returns True for me.

Comment: How can I get the function to return 'true' though?

Comment: Every number is a perfect square, 11 is a perfect square of 11**0.5. This questions is only interesting if we talk about integers.

Comment: Yea, I just went full stupid. Sorry about that xD

Comment: Note that this will fail for sufficiently large numbers because `math.sqrt` only has double precision, but to get around that you'd need to use an arbitrary-precision float calculation (like in `Decimal`) or implement an integer root algorithm (of which several are given in the question Haidro linked.)

Answer (score 6):

```
lambda n: math.sqrt(n) % 1 == 0
```

Comment: how can I get the function to return 'true' and 'false' though?

Comment: It's a boolean, therefore you *will* get true or false like any other conditional test.

Comment: Invoke it.  `(lambda n: math.sqrt(n) % 1 == 0)(16)`.  Or `sq = lambda n: math.sqrt(n) % 1 == 0; sq(16)`.

Comment: or define it as a function: `def isSquare(n): return math.sqrt(n) % 1 == 0`

Answer (score 1):

Could use the modulo operator:

```
>>> def perfectsquare(n):
...     return not n % n**0.5
...
>>> perfectsquare(36)
True
>>> perfectsquare(37)
False
>>> perfectsquare(25)
True
>>> perfectsquare(4215378*4215378)
True
```