# How to find perfect squares in a range efficiently when the inputs are large numbers in Python

Tags: python, largenumber, perfect-square

The question is how to find perfect squares in a given range efficiently when the inputs are very large numbers. My solution is giving `Time Limit Exceeded` error. I have already checked the following links, but they didn't solve my problem:
- [Python Program on Perfect Squares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508859/python-program-on-perfect-squares)
- [How could I check if a number is a perfect square?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489435/how-could-i-check-if-a-number-is-a-perfect-square)
- [Fastest way to determine if an integer's square root is an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295579/fastest-way-to-determine-if-an-integers-square-root-is-an-integer) (I have no idea how to implement the solution given in this link in Python).

The problem question is:

> Input Format: First line contains T, the number of testcases. T test cases follow, each in a newline.  Each testcase contains two space separated integers denoting A and B. Find all the perfect squares in the range A and B (both inclusive).

Example of an input:

```
2
3 9
17 24
```

The code I wrote is:

```
import math
def is_perfect_square(n):
    return n % n**0.5 == 0

t = int(raw_input())
for i in range(t):
    numbers = map(int, raw_input().split())
    count = 0
    for j in xrange(numbers[0], numbers[1] + 1): # I also tried range() which gave memory error
        if (is_perfect_square(j)):
            count = count + 1

    print count
```

While this code is working for smaller numbers, it is giving `Time limit exceeded` error for large inputs.

(NOTE : `gmpy` is not an option as the code has to be run on an online compiler which does not have the `gmpy` module)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of looping from `A` to `B` and checking for perfect squares, why not just loop through the integers from `sqrt(A)` to `sqrt(B)` and square each, giving you your answer.

For example, let's find the square numbers between 1000 and 2000:

```
sqrt(1000) = 31.6  -->  32  (need the ceiling here)
sqrt(2000) = 44.7  -->  44  (need the floor here)
```

Therefore, our answer is:

```
322 = 1024
332 = 1089
342 = 1156
352 = 1225
362 = 1296
372 = 1369
382 = 1444
392 = 1521
402 = 1600
412 = 1681
422 = 1764
432 = 1849
442 = 1936
```

Comment: You've reversed your `floor` and `ceiling`. And you need to be careful of rounding in the `sqrt` result.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks, I've corrected the floor/ceiling mix-up.

Comment: here you will get error: >>> math.ceil(math.sqrt(17))
5.0
>>> math.floor(math.sqrt(24))
4.0
.

Comment: That worked. I just needed the count of perfect squares in that range, so by finding `a = int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(x)))` and `b = int(math.floor(math.sqrt(x)))` and then `print (b + 1) - a` did the job.

Answer (score 0):

this is what i have tried:

```
>>> def isperferct_square(n):
...     return int(math.sqrt(n))*int(math.sqrt(n)) == n
... 
>>> isperferct_square(10)
False
>>> isperferct_square(9)
True
>>> isperferct_square(10000000000000000000)
False
>>> isperferct_square(112312424354957359732985732897583297592735932)
False
>>> isperferct_square(10000000000)
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes in your code, like numbers = map(int, raw_input().split()) has to be outside of the loop. Same with counter=0. Anyway, here is a code for you that should work for even really high integer numbers:

```
t = map(int,raw_input().split())

def is_perfect_square(x):
    if x < 0:
        raise ValueError('square root not defined for negative numbers')
    n = int(x)
    if n == 0:
        return False
    a, b = divmod(n.bit_length(), 2)
    x = 2**(a+b)
    while True:
        y = (x + n//x)//2
        if y >= x:
            return x
        x = y

count = 0
for i in t:
    if is_perfect_square(i)**2 == i:
        count+=1

print count
```